Going to future kind of movie
I recently watched a scene from a movie from Facebook, and I am just curious to know the film name. Sadly I don't have the link to the video right now. But the scene goes like this.
I think, the movie is related to some sort of time travel theory, i am not sure though. A girl goes to the future, but nobody could see her. See walks near a group of people and sees the vehicles the people use in the future. And then she climbs aboard a train, goes to a rocket launching station where few astronauts are about to go to space. The rocket launching mechanism is different, unlike the current technology, the rockets goes in a track like a roller coaster before they are being launched. Finally the girl try to get into a rocket, but she couldn't, the scene ends up with the girl being walking with hip level water at current time. Seems like she lost the power or something.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNzukD8pS_s

@cde the answer may be same for both the questions, but my question is not the duplicate of that question. I explained a different scene and the question you have marked as duplicate explains a different scene, but from the same movie.

@cde I didn't see that trailer b4, I didn't know that she had a ring like object, I was thinking she just travelled to future, didn't know she could see another dimension.

@RamarajT Identification questions are marked duplicate based on the movie or episode it is about, not based on the specific scene you ask about. It's just procedure, its not held against you.
